# Won't let me pick proprietary drivers in "Additional Drivers" menu?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I have an AMD Radeon HD 7520G graphics card on my HP Pavilion g6 laptop. I'm trying to play a game called Toontown Rewritten -- however the game appears only in a very weird form, with no floor and only lines. I've had this problem before and I fixed it by picking a different drivers in the "Additional Drivers" menu. Somehow the drivers reverted themselves or something and now whenever I click the proprietary drivers, it picks the X.Org.X drivers by itself when I click apply.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday i switched for the x org drivers and i was also unable to pick the proprietary drivers, so i did the following:

> sudo su
>   apt-get update
>   apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-dev
>   
>   if you want to get updates for the fglrx (proprietary driver) do the following instead:
>   
>       sudo su
>       add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
>       apt-get update
>       apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-dev